# How to include 3rd party dll resources file into install package

Tags: c#, setup-project, localized

I have two projects, both of them provides localizable support.

Project A generate `ProjectA.dll` and `ProjectA.resources.dll` (in zh-Hans folder)

Project B reference to `ProjectA.dll` (Project A and Project B in different solution).

create setup project for Project B with Visual Studio Installer. Added **Primary output from ProjectB** and **Localized resources from ProjectB**.

But it looks `ProjectA.resources.dll` didn't included in setup project. Can any one tell me what is the right way to include localized resources of Project A into setup project of Project B?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a reference of ProjectA.dll into ProjectB solution.

simply right click on the Reference in the solution explorer and click on Add.
then browse your dll and add its reference into the ProjectB solution.
It might work for you.

Comment: to support different language, i have three folders (ko for Korean, zh-CN,zh-Hans for chinese) contains ProjectA.resources.dll, but i can only reference one of them.

Comment: If you want to support different languages, then why not you used the App_localResources?

Comment: You can generate your `meta:Rescorcekeys` from your design view. VS will automatically generate it and the you can make rescourses files for your required languages. And use the culture in web.config, So in this way you can give multilanguage support for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Find the relevant .dll file in the project,
Right click it - > properties,
Set the "Copy Local" value to true

Comment: "Copy Local" already set to True, but setup project can't determine resource dependents

Comment: What kind of setup project are you using ? You can choose which dll's would be on the setup project